# Xcode swift table inside table

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a table view controller which has two different types of cells, one switches to the detail view of that cell, now the other cell is the problem one. I want that Cell to animate a swipe to make it look like its moving to a second table although it satys on the same and update the table view, so that it makes it look like I have a table inside a table without the need to make a second or thirt table view controller.

How could I do the animation and update part inside of one table view ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it like that? What is the high cost of creating a VC (potentially a generic reusable one)?

Comment: If that easyer, shure XD how can make a reusable table ?

Comment: I know nothing about your app, so it's hard / impossible to say. It depends what it is now, but take your current controller and make the input a property you can set and then instantiate a new one, set its details and push it

Comment: What seems obvious to you, as the developer, won't be obvious to your users.  Before you get wrapped up in how to do this, consider how the user would a) intuitively know this gesture, and b) how they are to return from the "second" table to the "first" table.

Comment: Ok let me refrase it, how can I make a table seems like I have multible table views in a row altough I only have one (INCLUDING ALL navigation controller functiond, such as back button and swipe animation)?